# How to send data from html form to view in django

Tags: django

So I have an html form built with Foundation that collects information from user that I must then store in database. I attempt to connect the form to a view as follows:

```
<form data-abide action = "{% url 'User:user_signup_save' %}" method="POST">
```

The view I am attempting to send this data to is

```
def user_signup_save(request):
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Reverse for 'user_signup_save' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: This isn't a question about forms, but about URLs. Do you have a urls.py? Do you have a URL named "user_signup_save" in it? Perhaps you should post that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give name to your views via urls. 
You can check it out from [named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)